# increase performance of opencl

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencl

I am trying to implement some image processing algorithm using opencl. But as i see when i use opencl it is taking around 0.5 ms to complet one process i.e one frame. Isn't there any way than i initialize the opencl parameters only once using class object declaration than only call a function run the main kernel? I tried like this by creating class but as i find context, device can't be declared and used seperately and needs to be created each time.

```
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std;
namespace Color {
enum Code {
  FG_RED = 31,
  FG_GREEN = 32,
  FG_BLUE = 34,
  FG_DEFAULT = 39,
  BG_RED = 41,
  BG_GREEN = 42,
  BG_BLUE = 44,
  BG_DEFAULT = 49
};
class Modifier {
  Code code;

 public:
  Modifier(Code pCode) : code(pCode) {}
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Modifier& mod) {
    return os << "\033[" << mod.code << "m";
  }
};
}  // namespace Color
class useOpenCL {
 public:
  int size = 294400;
  std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
  std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
  cl::Platform default_platform;
  cl::Device default_device;
  cl::Program::Sources sources;
  std::string kernel_code;
  cl::Kernel kernel_add;
  cl::Buffer buffer_A;

  useOpenCL();
  ~useOpenCL() {}
  void backgroundSub();
};

useOpenCL::useOpenCL() {
  Color::Modifier green(Color::FG_GREEN);
  Color::Modifier red(Color::FG_RED);
  Color::Modifier def(Color::FG_DEFAULT);
  // get all platforms (drivers)
  cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);
  if (all_platforms.size() == 0) {
    std::cout << red << " No platforms found. Check OpenCL installation!" << def
              << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  default_platform = all_platforms[0];
  std::cout << green << "Using platform: " << def
            << default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>() << std::endl;

  // get default device of the default platform
  default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
  if (all_devices.size() == 0) {
    std::cout << red << " No devices found. Check OpenCL installation!" << def
              << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  default_device = all_devices[0];
  std::cout << green << "Using device: " << def
            << default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << std::endl;

  // kernel calculates for each element C=A+B
  kernel_code =
      "   void kernel simple_add(global const int* A, global const int* B, "
      "global int* C){       "
      "       C[get_global_id(0)]=A[get_global_id(0)]+B[get_global_id(0)];     "
      "            "
      "   }                                                                    "
      "           ";
  sources.push_back({kernel_code.c_str(), kernel_code.length()});
}

void useOpenCL::backgroundSub() {
  int A[size], B[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    A[i] = i;
    B[i] = i + 1;
  }
  auto start1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  cl::Context context({default_device});

  cl::Program program(context, sources);
  if (program.build({default_device}) != CL_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << " Error building: "
              << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device)
              << "\n";
    exit(1);
  }
  // create buffers on the device
  cl::Buffer buffer_A(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * size);
  cl::Buffer buffer_B(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * size);
  cl::Buffer buffer_C(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * size);

  // create queue to which we will push commands for the device.
  cl::CommandQueue queue(context, default_device);

  // write arrays A and B to the device
  queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * size, A);
  queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_B, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * size, B);

  // run the kernel
  /*cl::KernelFunctor
  simple_add(cl::Kernel(program,"simple_add"),queue,cl::NullRange,cl::NDRange(10),cl::NullRange);
  simple_add(buffer_A,buffer_B,buffer_C);*/

  // alternative way to run the kernel
  kernel_add.setArg(0, buffer_A);
  kernel_add.setArg(1, buffer_B);
  kernel_add.setArg(2, buffer_C);
  queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_add, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(size),
                             cl::NullRange);
  queue.finish();

  int C[size];
  // read result C from the device to array C
  queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_C, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * size, C);
  /*std::cout<<" result: \n";
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
      std::cout<<C[i]<<"\t";
  }*/
  auto stop1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto duration1 = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop1 - start1);
  auto FPS = 1000000.0 / duration1.count();
  cout << "Segmentation FPS=" << FPS << "\t"
       << "Execution Time(sec)=" << duration1.count() / 1000000.0 << endl;
}

int main() {
  useOpenCL img;
  while (true) {
    img.backgroundSub();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It is giving me below results:

```
Segmentation FPS=13.2557    Execution Time(sec)=0.075439
Segmentation FPS=15.7602    Execution Time(sec)=0.063451
Segmentation FPS=14.3872    Execution Time(sec)=0.069506
Segmentation FPS=12.7525    Execution Time(sec)=0.078416
```

Which is not good since fps is only 12, 13 fps. So how can i make this program faster?

Comment: How do you compile your project? Do you have optimisation enabled? What are your exact compile flags?

Comment: I am compiling using cmake or say catkin by adding the include_directory and link_library option after installation of opencl in ubuntu platform.

Comment: Try with a Release build at least, with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`. That will enable some optimisation and make your code faster. Don't forget to also compile all your libraries in release mode. Also, system libraries like the one installed by apt will already be in release mode.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you mean by "I tried like this by creating class but as i find context, device can't be declared and used seperately and needs to be created each time." What's wrong with moving your context, program, buffers, and queue variables into the class as well, and only initialising them once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the initialization part that you only need to call once in the beginning in the constructor. This initialization should contain ALL memory allocation, OpenCL C code compilation and any initial memory transfers from host to device:

```c
useOpenCL::useOpenCL() {
  Color::Modifier green(Color::FG_GREEN);
  Color::Modifier red(Color::FG_RED);
  Color::Modifier def(Color::FG_DEFAULT);
  // get all platforms (drivers)
  cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);
  if (all_platforms.size() == 0) {
    std::cout << red << " No platforms found. Check OpenCL installation!" << def
              << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  default_platform = all_platforms[0];
  std::cout << green << "Using platform: " << def
            << default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>() << std::endl;

  // get default device of the default platform
  default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
  if (all_devices.size() == 0) {
    std::cout << red << " No devices found. Check OpenCL installation!" << def
              << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  default_device = all_devices[0];
  std::cout << green << "Using device: " << def
            << default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << std::endl;

  // kernel calculates for each element C=A+B
  kernel_code =
      "   void kernel simple_add(global const int* A, global const int* B, "
      "global int* C){       "
      "       C[get_global_id(0)]=A[get_global_id(0)]+B[get_global_id(0)];     "
      "            "
      "   }                                                                    "
      "           ";
  sources.push_back({kernel_code.c_str(), kernel_code.length()});

  context = cl::Context({default_device});

  program = cl::Program(context, sources);
  if (program.build({default_device}) != CL_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << " Error building: "
              << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device)
              << "\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  // create queue to which we will push commands for the device.
  queue = cl::CommandQueue(context, default_device);

  // create buffers on host
  int A[size], B[size];
  int C[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    A[i] = i;
    B[i] = i + 1;
  }

  // create buffers on the device
  buffer_A = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * size);
  buffer_B = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * size);
  buffer_C = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * size);

  // write arrays A and B to the device
  queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * size, A);
  queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_B, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * size, B);

  // alternative way to run the kernel
  kernel_add.setArg(0, buffer_A);
  kernel_add.setArg(1, buffer_B);
  kernel_add.setArg(2, buffer_C);
}
```

Therefore make `context`, `program`, `queue`, `buffer_A`, `buffer_B`, `buffer_C` member variables of your class `useOpenCL`. Especially the memory allocation and compilation take a long time, so do them only once and reuse the buffers.

```c
class useOpenCL {
 public:
  int size = 294400;
  std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
  std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
  cl::Platform default_platform;
  cl::Device default_device;
  cl::Program::Sources sources;
  std::string kernel_code;
  cl::Kernel kernel_add;

  cl::Buffer buffer_A;
  cl::Buffer buffer_B;
  cl::Buffer buffer_C;

  cl::Context context;
  cl::Program program;
  cl::CommandQueue queue;

  useOpenCL();
  ~useOpenCL() {}
  void backgroundSub();
};
```

Then only the kernel call and eventually memory transfers host<->device remain for every frame calculation:

```c
void useOpenCL::backgroundSub() {
  auto start1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  // write arrays A and B to the device (ONLY IF NECESSARY FOR EVERY FRAME)
  //queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * size, A);
  //queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_B, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * size, B);

  // run the kernel
  queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_add, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(size),
                             cl::NullRange);

  // read result C from the device to array C
  queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_C, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * size, C);

  queue.finish();

  auto stop1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto duration1 = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop1 - start1);
  auto FPS = 1000000.0 / duration1.count();
  cout << "Segmentation FPS=" << FPS << "\t"
       << "Execution Time(sec)=" << duration1.count() / 1000000.0 << endl;
}
```

The latter code can be called over and over again and should be much faster than if you re-initialize everything over and over again. Also make sure that `size` is large enough, otherwise the GPU might not be utilized at its full potential and the latencies for host<->device memory transfers will make every frame disproportunately slower.